# Should Data Transfer Objects (DTOs) be used to bind UI too?

Tags: kotlin, mvvm, clean-architecture, android-mvvm

My question is simple:

I have a large Data Transfer Object like:

```
data class Terminal(
  @Expose
  @SerializedName("inspector_code")
  var inspectorCode:String,

  @Expose
  @SerializedName("inspector_id")
  var inspectorId:Long
  [x50]
)
```

Most of them are used for the business logic, for http requests, transaction verifying,

few of them are used for the UI.

Should this type of DTO be used in the presentation layer too ? or i can have a different one and use converters to build a **presentation object**, does this even exists in mvvm arhitecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DTO should be converted to a local model class. This does remove the coupling of your endpoints and your UI and allows a more flexible architecture.

Translating a DTO can be done in something like a Repository, which in turn uses your datasource that returns the DTO.

Since the question looks to be targeted at Android (Android-mvvm), you can have a look at this guide here as well https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture

Comment: Tnx, can you also give me an example of a Local Model Class ?

Comment: That depends on your application and your use cases. But in general if you want to follow the approach to having your data source model not leaking into the UI, you can have something like this from the Repository and above use the model class Terminal, for the client datasource TerminalDto and e.g. for the DB datasource TerminalEntity. The Repository can then translates between Terminal, TerminalDto and TerminalEntity depending where the data should go.

Answer (score 0):

I personally add a method in every Dto class that allows me to turn it into a Model object. If there are any changes in either the the model or the Dto class  this will result in an exception at compile time notifying me of the need to adjust this function. sometimes you also need to turn objects from Model into Dto types and here I generally also prefer to put this function or constructor in the Dto class; that way the higher layers of my architecture (namely the domain layer) remain agnostic as to the peculiarities of the backend that I am using.

here an example where I presune that my backend is incapable of storing booleans directly. As is shown my Bean model object is unaware and indifferent as to how it is stored all the loginc is directly attatched to the Dto

```
data class Bean(val name:String, val isApproved:Boolean)


data class BeanDto(val name:String, val isApproved:Int){

   constructor(bean:Bean) : this(name=bean.name, isApproved=if (bean.isApproved) 1 else 0) 

   fun toBean()=Bean(
       name=name,
       isApproved = isApproved==1
   )
}
```

I am happy to hear comments regarding what others think about this approach